# Error trying to download SSRS reports to a local folder using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I have (below) a Powershell script that takes source and destination parameters, then downloads all SSRS report files from the source folder into the destination folder:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$sourceFolder, # Folder on the SSRS Report Server that contains reports, relative to root (eg "/Reports")
    [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$destinationFolder, # Absolute path to which report files should be downloaded
    [string]$reportServerURI = "http://localhost/Reports"
)

Get-RsFolderContent -ReportServerUri $reportServerURI `
                    -RsFolder $sourceFolder | `
    Where-Object TypeName -eq "Report" | `
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | `
        Out-RsCatalogItem -ReportServerUri $reportServerURI `
                          -Destination $destinationFolder
```

The call to `Get-RsFolderContent` causes the script to fail immediately with the below error:

```
Failed to establish proxy connection to http://localhost/Reports/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an error downloading 
'http://localhost/Reports/ReportService2010.asmx'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ReportingServicesTools\0.0.4.7\Functions\Utilities\New-RsWebServiceProxy.ps1:114 char:9
+         throw (New-Object System.Exception("Failed to establish proxy ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to establish proxy connection to http://localhost/Reports/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an e 
   rror downloading 'http://localhost/Reports/ReportService2010.asmx'.
```

I have tried this script both on a server, as well as against the SSRS instance installed on my local machine (SQL2014 in both cases). Any assistance with this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't think that the RDL files existed anywhere on the server, other than in a SQL database?

Opening my SSRS server and searching for *.rdl seems to back that up...

Comment: @JonTout Report files become .rdl files once they are downloaded to a local folder.

Comment: so you've already "manually" downloaded the .rdl files to the network?

I've had to use UNC paths when copying files between servers, especially our SQL/SSRS server. (I've also had to get permission to log onto the servers using RDP)

`$source_path = "\\ssrs_vs12\e$\ReportFiles\"`
`$target_path = "\\ssrsv_1\e$\ReportFiles\"`

...then I use a  `ForEach-Object {Move-Item}`

Comment: @Cam any improvements on this one? I am having exactly the same issue

Comment: @GrayCat I managed to implement a solution using scripts found here: https://blogs.infosupport.com/managing-ssrs-reports-with-powershell/ hope this helps!

Comment: @Cam, you might want to answer your own question then, do that other people could see it straightaway

Comment: Answer was found here https://blogs.infosupport.com/managing-ssrs-reports-with-powershell/ thirty chars

Comment: I had the same issue and realized after checking Report Server Config Manager/Web Service URL the Virtual Directory was a custom name instead of report server.  Once I switched out ReportServer for CustomReporting it loaded fine.